# Why does the WebView html in my Mac app refuse to load JQuery or any external script?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, macos, webview, osx-lion

I have a simple index.html file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(function() {

        setInterval(function(){

          if (typeof Cocoa !== 'undefined') {

            Cocoa.log('JQuery loaded...');

          }

        }, 3000);

      });

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Testing script in objective c enviroment.</h1>
    <div id="container" class="col">
      <p>Paragraph 1</p>
      <p>content goes here</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

loaded from a WebView subclass in my AppDelegate:

appDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property NSWindow *webWindow;
@property myWebView *myWV;

@end

// ...
```

appDelegate.m

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
#import "myWebView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

// ...

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {


    CGRect webRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

    self.webWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:webRect styleMask:NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    self.webWindow.contentView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:webRect];

    self.myWV = [[myWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webRect frameName:@"myWV" groupName:@"webViews"];
    self.myWV.UIDelegate = self;
    self.myWV.resourceLoadDelegate = self;
    self.myWV.frameLoadDelegate = self;

    [self.webWindow.contentView addSubview:self.myWV];
    [self.webWindow orderFront:NSApp];

    NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index"
                                                         ofType:@"html"
                                                    inDirectory:@""];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
    [[self.myWV mainFrame] loadRequest:request];

}

// associate js "Cocoa.log" function with -logJavaScriptString: method
+ (NSString *)webScriptNameForSelector:(SEL)sel
{
    if(sel == @selector(logJavaScriptString:))
        return @"log";
    return nil;
}

//this allows JavaScript to call the -logJavaScriptString: method
+ (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)sel
{
    if(sel == @selector(logJavaScriptString:))
        return NO;
    return YES;
}

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    NSLog(@"webView loaded");
    [[self.myWV windowScriptObject] setValue:self forKey:@"Cocoa"];   
}

- (void)logJavaScriptString:(NSString *)logText
{
    NSLog(@"JavaScript: %@",logText);
}
```

Why does nothing inside `$(function() {});` get called? If I place the interval log function outside the JQuery onReady function, it does start to call the correct method after a few seconds.

Is there some cross-site policy issue going on that's preventing scripts from being loaded? If so, how can I disable it? Why isn't jQuery loading?

Comment: Any errors in the console? What browser are you using? If the url you are testing on isn't https you could be getting a secure/insecure issue and have to remove the https and replace it with http. The most common way to handle this is to use `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"` instead of `src="https://etc"`. The previous method will change the protocol to match the current url protocol

Comment: I've tested the html in Chrome, and it works fine (it pulls the JQuery and runs `onReady` correctly even with the `https`).

Comment: Different browsers respond to secure/insecure issues differently. Are you saying that all your code works fine in Chrome or that it fires the onReady function in chrome but still fails?

Comment: Well, in Chrome there's no Cocoa object obviously, but code such as `console.log('JQuery loaded')` does get run inside the `onReady` function. So I guess it doesn't fail, it that's what you mean.

Comment: I just tested it with `http` instead of `https` and it seems to be working now. Why doesn't the WebKit in `WebView` get along with `https`? Is there some way to enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js
```

to

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js
```

and now it works. If anyone knows why `WebView` doesn't like https, let me know in the comments.